# Setting extent and geographic projection in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r

I have a raster and a shapefile that I am attempting to view and process in R. The shape file "`ER_11.1`" has the following specs:

```
> ER_11.1
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
nfeatures   : 22 
extent      : -1989641, -1450736, -1748693, -208349.6  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs 
nvariables  : 8
names       : NA_L2CODE,                NA_L2NAME, NA_L1CODE,                NA_L1NAME,                       NA_L2KEY,                     NA_L1KEY,   Shape_Leng,   Shape_Area 
min values  :      11.1, MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA,        11, MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA, 11.1  MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA, 11  MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA,     331.1174, 1.483274e+08 
max values  :      11.1, MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA,        11, MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA, 11.1  MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA, 11  MEDITERRANEAN CALIFORNIA, 5417939.1114, 8.472524e+04 
>
```

The raster file "bio_1" has the following specs.

```
# Set up a raster "template" to use in rasterize based on a enxisting layer extent 
bio_1<-raster ('E:/Ecoregions Models/Border Bioclim/ModelVariables/bio_1.asc')
#add projection information to match the shapefile to the raster files 
projection(bio_1) <- "+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs"

> bio_1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 324, 444, 143856  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -125, -88, 18.5, 45.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : E:\Ecoregions Models\Border Bioclim\ModelVariables\bio_1.asc 
names       : bio_1
```

Its clear that the projection and extents are different but when I change the projection, the two files still do not map on top of each other.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have corrected my issue for now. This command converts my bio_1 layer to the same coordinate system as my Ecoregions shapefile and thus they are easily plotted on top of each other.

```
bio_1.new<- projectRaster(bio_1,  crs="+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs")
```